# Different Time in Database and Collection

Tags: magento2, timezone

I am Facing a Strange issue.i have some data in `report_viewed_product_index` table

You can see this

[image]

I have created a Model for this table and Getting Data

But in Collection, I am getting a different time

[image]

Anyone please help me to solve this Issue

My Laptop Time Zone and Store time Zone is the same...